# BATMAN & OMNET++

Tags: routes, protocols, omnet++

I am a newbie to OMNET++.

I have a reasonable Background of BATMAN.

Now I want to implement BATMAN in OMNET++. I have a code of BATMAN in NED language. But I have no idea of how to compile it.

So far I have made a .ned file and copy pasted the code lines there.But obviously It had lots of error.What is the proper way to run a protocol in OMNET++.
Code: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/25196881/

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some modules, which are imported in the copied .ned-file are missing.
It would be helpful, if you provide some more information about you errors and what you did exactly.

Have you installed and imported inet? Do you have the .cc and .h for your

```
        @class(Batman);
```

class?

Comment: Thank you Hennsen! I just created a simple .NED file (File type for Adhoc wireless networks), placed it in the folder of INET<examples<manetrouting<batman.It created *.ini  and README files with it.Then i pasted the code.The errors are  *Imported NED type not found: Cotrol Channel"same goes for AdhocHost.

Comment: Resource Path Location Type'AdhocHost': no such module type.
Resource Path Location Type 'ChannelControl': no such module type.
Resource Path Location Type 'IPv4NetworkConfigurator': no such module type.
Path Location Type imported NED type not found'inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator'.
Resource Path Location Type
imported NED type not found: 'inet.nodes.inet.AdhocHost'.
Resource Path Location Type imported NED type not found: 'inet.world.radio.ChannelControl'
Errors in detail..

Comment: I do have  a .cc file but dont know how to integrate it and I dn have a .h file yet.

Comment: The importing of the inet modules doesn't work here.

You should really do the tic-toc-tutorial:
https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/

After that take a look at the inet-wireless-turoial:
https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/tutorials/wireless/

There you get a basic knowledge about how things work.

Comment: Thank you Hennsen! Much appreciated.. I'll proceed accordingly.

Comment: I would like to point out that recent versions of INET does NOT contain BATMAN. You will need INETMANET (a fork of INET) which contains the external MANET protocols.

Comment: Thank you @Rubi, I got a project having Batman implemented in OMNET, trying to follow and implement it.